# How precisely is the へ particle to be understood in 「そこへ、…」 when it means "then"?

Tags: particle-へ

The sentence in question ([source](http://life.ou.edu/stories/sarukani.html)):

> そこへ、猿がやって来ました。

It is translated as "Then, the monkey approached".

From what I understand, he へ particle normally is used with a verb to imply it's general direction, a more specific version of に. I don't quite see how this meaning would apply here.

Comment: They're not literally translating every word.  そこへ just means "to there".  I think they're just trying to get a smooth english translation.

Comment: @A.Ellett Ah, that makes sense, though I could swear I've seen 「そこへ、…」 translated as "Then,…" quite a few times. I guess that's just a case of different lead-in phrases with different literal meanings being used in the same way.

Comment: are you sure you’re not thinking of それで

Comment: @A.Ellett Not 100%, but I'm pretty certain it was そこへ, but I can't remember where, so I unfortunately can't check.

Comment: I don't doubt you've seen "そこへ" translated as "then", since "そこ" can refer to a particular point in time, or a particular point in a sequence of events, as attested by dictionaries.https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E5%87%A6%E3%83%BB%E5%85%B6%E6%89%80-313949
(The relevant sense is ㋒ 今述べた場面。その場面。その時。. 場面 means scene, juncture or something like that.)