# そこへ with くる in a single sentence

Tags: grammar, words

What is the reason that these are paired up like this in this sentence: "そこへ少女がやってくる"

Comment: Why is it confusing? 'A girl came *to* that place'

Comment: Comments to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82296/45489) may answer your question.

Comment: Are you asking why the verb くる is used instead of いく when the destination is そこ and not ここ?